# AS3: Really weird "inaccessable" error when referencing document root object

Tags: actionscript-3, object, methods, document-root

Alright, I am pulling my hair out on this one. Got this problem at around 9 last night and was up until 5 trying to fix it, and then all day so far (it's already about 9 PM again) trying to fix it. I've tried everything I can think of.

Alright, so I'm trying to reference the document object from various classes in my class library. Everything seemed to be going peachy until I started getting this random, weird error. I thought maybe it was Flash acting up all of a sudden but I tried it on my Mac as well and I get the same error.

Basically no matter WHAT I do, I am getting the error:

> 1195: Attempted access of inaccessible
>   method getSessionHandler through a
>   reference with static type pim:PClient

It's a lot of code, but here is the full code.

```
// PClient.as
package pim
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    import pim.gui.PGConsole;
    import pim.loader.PCommandLoader;
    import pim.loader.PGUILoader;
    import pim.loader.PSessionLoader;

    /**
     * The main client MovieClip for the client
     * @author Qix
     */
    public class PClient extends MovieClip
    {       
        private var _guiLoader:PGUILoader;
        private var _sessionLoader:PSessionLoader;
        private var _cmdLoader:PCommandLoader;

        private static var _singleton:PClient;

        /**
         * Constructor
         * @author Qix
         */
        public function PClient()
        {
            // Trace
            trace("Client(): Client initiated");

            // Call super
            super();

            // Set Singleton instance
            PClient._singleton = this;

            // Create session handler/loader
            _sessionLoader = new PSessionLoader();

            // Create command loader
            _cmdLoader = new PCommandLoader();

            // Create GUI loader + Add to the canvas
            _guiLoader = new PGUILoader();
            addChild(_guiLoader);

            // Call on start
            onStart();
        }

        /**
         * Gets the singleton instance of the client
         * @author Qix
         * @return The singleton instance of the object
         */
        public static function getInstance():PClient
        {
            // Return
            return PClient._singleton;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the GUILoader instance
         * @author Qix
         * @return The GUI Loader instance
         */
        public function getGUILoader():PGUILoader
        {
            // Trace
            trace("pim.PClient.getGUILoader():");

            // Return
            return _guiLoader;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the session handler/loader object
         * @author Qix
         * @return The session handler/loader object reference
         */
        public function getSessionHandler():PSessionLoader
        {
            // Trace
            trace("pim.PClient.getSessionHandler():");

            // Return
            return _sessionLoader;

        }

        /**
         * Returns the command loader/handler
         * @author Qix
         * @return Returns the command loader/handler object
         */
        public function getCommandHandler():PCommandLoader
        {
            // Trace
            trace("pim.PClient.getCommandHandler():");

            // Return
            return _cmdLoader;
        }

        /**
         * Called when the client has loaded and is ready to start whatever
         * @author Qix
         */
        public function onStart():void
        {
            // Trace
            trace("Client.onStart(): Starting startup commands...");

            // Create console window
            var con:PGConsole = new PGConsole();
            _guiLoader.addGUI(con, "console");

            // Echo
            getCommandHandler().exec("echo hello!");

        }
    }
}
```

and...

```
// PCommandLoader.as
package pim.loader 
{
    import pim.gui.PGConsole;
    import pim.gui.iPGWindow;
    import pim.PClient;
    /**
     * Handles PIM commands
     * @author Qix
     */
    public final class PCommandLoader
    {
        private var _funcs:Array;

        /**
         * Constructor
         * @author Qix
         */
        public function PCommandLoader() 
        {
            // Trace
            trace("PCommandLoader(): Instantiated");


            // Instantiate vectors
            _funcs = new Array();

            // Setup basic commands here
            addCMD("echo", c_echo);
            addCMD("set", c_set);
            addCMD("get", c_get);
        }

        /**
         * Executes a command
         * @param   cmd
         */
        public function exec(cmd:String):void
        {
            // Trace
            trace("PCommandLoader.exec(): " + cmd);

            // Get command
            var cmdspl:Array = cmd.split(" ");
            var cmdn:String = cmdspl[0];
            cmdn = cmdn.toLowerCase();

            // Construct parameters
            var param:String = cmd.substr(cmdn.length + 1);

            // Return if command doesn't exist
            if (!(cmdn in _funcs))
            {
                // Trace and return
                trace("PCommandLoader.exec(): Command \"" + cmdn + "\" doesn't exist!");

                return;
            }

            // Distribute command
            _funcs[cmdn].call(null, param);
        }

        /**
         * Adds a command to the command list
         * @param   name    The name of the command
         * @param   cb
         */
        public function addCMD(name:String, cb:Function):void
        {
            // Set name to lowercase
            name = name.toLowerCase();

            // Trace
            trace("PCommandLoader.addCMD(): Adding command \"" + name + "\"");

            // Warn if already created!
            if (name in _funcs)
                trace("PCommandLoader.addCMD(): WARNING! Command already created. You are over-riding this 

command!");

            // Add
            _funcs[name] = cb;
        }

        /**
         * Attempts to print to the console
         * @author Qix
         * @param   str The string to print
         * @param   col The color to make the string
         */
        public function conOut(str:String, col:String = "#AAAAAA"):void
        {
            // Try to get GUI
            var p:iPGWindow = PClient.getInstance().getGUILoader().getGUI("console");

            // If it doesn't exist...
            if (p == null)
                return;

            // Echo out!
            (p as PGConsole).appendText(str, col);
        }

        /* Basic Command Callbacks */

        /**
         * CMD: A basic command; Echos out whatever is passed to it.
         * @author Qix
         */
        private function c_echo(str:String):void
        {
            // Trace
            trace("CMD - ECHO: " + str);

            // Output
            conOut(str);
        }

        /**
         * CMD: A basic command; Sets a session value
         * @author Qix
         */
        private function c_set(str:String):void
        {
            // Get params
            var params:Array = str.split(" ");

            // If insufficient number of parameters
            if (params.length == 1)
            {
                // Trace and return
                trace("CMD - SET: ERROR! Expected 2 parameters, got 1.")
                // TODO Echo to console (c_set error)
                return;

            }

            // Trace
            trace("CMD - SET: Setting " + params[0] + " to " + params[1]);

            // Convert to int if necessary...
            var toNum:Number = Number(params[1]);

            // Check if the number conversion worked or not and set the value
            // Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
            //1195: Attempted access of inaccessible method getSessionHandler through a reference with static 

type pim:PClient.   PCommandLoader.as   /PimOnlineClient/[source path] lib/pim/loader   line 146    Flex Problem

            if (isNaN(toNum))
                PClient.getInstance().getSessionHandler().setVal(params[0], params[1]);     // String
            else
                PClient.getInstance().getSessionHandler().setVal(params[0], toNum);         // 

Number
        }

        /**
         * CMD: A basic command; gets a session value
         * @author Qix
         */
        private function c_get(str:String):void
        {
            // Get params
            var params:Array = str.split(" ");

            // Trace
            trace("CMD - GET: Getting the value of \"" + params[0] + "\"");

            // Get value
            var val:* = PClient.getInstance().getSessionHandler().getVal(params[0]);

            // If val is null (failed)
            if (val == null)
            {
                // Trace and return
                trace("CMD - GET: ERROR! \"" + params[0] + "\" doesn't exist!");
                conOut("\"" + params[0] + "\" does not exist!");
                return;
            }

            // Output
            conOut(String(val));
        }

    }

}
```

Alright so right now, I have sort of a singleton reference that I'm using so I can reference the document object from any class (without the need to pass the client object to each class that needs to use it). I'm pretty sure I've done this before and had it work, but obviously it is not.

I've even tried passing the client object (`this`) to the `PCommandLoader` object and it STILL gives this really really strange error (that is WITHOUT the use of any static methods, etc.)

WHAT THE HECK IS GOING ON? I've tried EVERYTHING -- even a class that holds the PClient object reference, which was really messy -- and it still gives this really, really weird message. Even referencing the `root` property on movieclips gives me this error. The movie was working great and then magically it started doing this. I backed everything up and undid everything back to pretty much empty script files and it wouldn't let me compile since...

I'm going crazy here! Help?

**EDIT** Alright, with strict mode set to *off*, it compiles and works 100% as expected. What gives?

**EDIT** Here is the describeType on PClient.getInstance() right before the error:

```
<type name="pim::PClient" base="flash.display::MovieClip" isDynamic="false" isFinal="false" isStatic="false">
  <extendsClass type="flash.display::MovieClip"/>
  <extendsClass type="flash.display::Sprite"/>
  <extendsClass type="flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer"/>
  <extendsClass type="flash.display::InteractiveObject"/>
  <extendsClass type="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <extendsClass type="flash.events::EventDispatcher"/>
  <extendsClass type="Object"/>
  <implementsInterface type="flash.events::IEventDispatcher"/>
  <implementsInterface type="flash.display::IBitmapDrawable"/>
  <accessor name="blendShader" access="writeonly" type="flash.display::Shader" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <accessor name="scenes" access="readonly" type="Array" declaredBy="flash.display::MovieClip"/>
  <accessor name="alpha" access="readwrite" type="Number" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <accessor name="tabEnabled" access="readwrite" type="Boolean" declaredBy="flash.display::InteractiveObject"/>
  <accessor name="currentFrameLabel" access="readonly" type="String" declaredBy="flash.display::MovieClip"/>
  <accessor name="currentLabels" access="readonly" type="Array" declaredBy="flash.display::MovieClip"/>
  <accessor name="currentLabel" access="readonly" type="String" declaredBy="flash.display::MovieClip"/>
  <accessor name="name" access="readwrite" type="String" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <accessor name="height" access="readwrite" type="Number" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <accessor name="buttonMode" access="readwrite" type="Boolean" declaredBy="flash.display::Sprite"/>
  <accessor name="dropTarget" access="readonly" type="flash.display::DisplayObject" declaredBy="flash.display::Sprite"/>
  <accessor name="hitArea" access="readwrite" type="flash.display::Sprite" declaredBy="flash.display::Sprite"/>
  <accessor name="numChildren" access="readonly" type="int" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer"/>
  <accessor name="tabIndex" access="readwrite" type="int" declaredBy="flash.display::InteractiveObject"/>
  <accessor name="scaleX" access="readwrite" type="Number" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <accessor name="scaleY" access="readwrite" type="Number" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <accessor name="textSnapshot" access="readonly" type="flash.text::TextSnapshot" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer"/>
  <accessor name="tabChildren" access="readwrite" type="Boolean" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer"/>
  <accessor name="focusRect" access="readwrite" type="Object" declaredBy="flash.display::InteractiveObject"/>
  <accessor name="doubleClickEnabled" access="readwrite" type="Boolean" declaredBy="flash.display::InteractiveObject"/>
  <accessor name="accessibilityImplementation" access="readwrite" type="flash.accessibility::AccessibilityImplementation" declaredBy="flash.display::InteractiveObject">
    <metadata name="Inspectable">
      <arg key="environment" value="none"/>
    </metadata>
  </accessor>
  <accessor name="enabled" access="readwrite" type="Boolean" declaredBy="flash.display::MovieClip"/>
  <accessor name="contextMenu" access="readwrite" type="flash.ui::ContextMenu" declaredBy="flash.display::InteractiveObject"/>
  <accessor name="parent" access="readonly" type="flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <accessor name="useHandCursor" access="readwrite" type="Boolean" declaredBy="flash.display::Sprite"/>
  <accessor name="soundTransform" access="readwrite" type="flash.media::SoundTransform" declaredBy="flash.display::Sprite"/>
  <accessor name="root" access="readonly" type="flash.display::DisplayObject" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <accessor name="x" access="readwrite" type="Number" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <accessor name="y" access="readwrite" type="Number" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <accessor name="mask" access="readwrite" type="flash.display::DisplayObject" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <accessor name="stage" access="readonly" type="flash.display::Stage" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <accessor name="z" access="readwrite" type="Number" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <accessor name="visible" access="readwrite" type="Boolean" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <accessor name="mouseChildren" access="readwrite" type="Boolean" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer"/>
  <accessor name="scaleZ" access="readwrite" type="Number" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <accessor name="graphics" access="readonly" type="flash.display::Graphics" declaredBy="flash.display::Sprite"/>
  <accessor name="mouseX" access="readonly" type="Number" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <accessor name="mouseY" access="readonly" type="Number" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <accessor name="rotation" access="readwrite" type="Number" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <accessor name="rotationX" access="readwrite" type="Number" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <accessor name="rotationY" access="readwrite" type="Number" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <accessor name="rotationZ" access="readwrite" type="Number" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <accessor name="trackAsMenu" access="readwrite" type="Boolean" declaredBy="flash.display::MovieClip"/>
  <accessor name="cacheAsBitmap" access="readwrite" type="Boolean" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <accessor name="opaqueBackground" access="readwrite" type="Object" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <accessor name="scrollRect" access="readwrite" type="flash.geom::Rectangle" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <accessor name="filters" access="readwrite" type="Array" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <accessor name="blendMode" access="readwrite" type="String" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <accessor name="transform" access="readwrite" type="flash.geom::Transform" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <accessor name="scale9Grid" access="readwrite" type="flash.geom::Rectangle" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <accessor name="currentScene" access="readonly" type="flash.display::Scene" declaredBy="flash.display::MovieClip"/>
  <accessor name="currentFrame" access="readonly" type="int" declaredBy="flash.display::MovieClip"/>
  <accessor name="framesLoaded" access="readonly" type="int" declaredBy="flash.display::MovieClip"/>
  <accessor name="totalFrames" access="readonly" type="int" declaredBy="flash.display::MovieClip"/>
  <accessor name="loaderInfo" access="readonly" type="flash.display::LoaderInfo" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <accessor name="mouseEnabled" access="readwrite" type="Boolean" declaredBy="flash.display::InteractiveObject"/>
  <accessor name="width" access="readwrite" type="Number" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <accessor name="accessibilityProperties" access="readwrite" type="flash.accessibility::AccessibilityProperties" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject"/>
  <method name="globalToLocal3D" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject" returnType="flash.geom::Vector3D">
    <parameter index="1" type="flash.geom::Point" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="play" declaredBy="flash.display::MovieClip" returnType="void"/>
  <method name="local3DToGlobal" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject" returnType="flash.geom::Point">
    <parameter index="1" type="flash.geom::Vector3D" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="addFrameScript" declaredBy="flash.display::MovieClip" returnType="void">
    <metadata name="Inspectable">
      <arg key="environment" value="none"/>
    </metadata>
  </method>
  <method name="gotoAndStop" declaredBy="flash.display::MovieClip" returnType="void">
    <parameter index="1" type="Object" optional="false"/>
    <parameter index="2" type="String" optional="true"/>
  </method>
  <method name="getChildIndex" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer" returnType="int">
    <parameter index="1" type="flash.display::DisplayObject" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="toString" declaredBy="flash.events::EventDispatcher" returnType="String"/>
  <method name="setChildIndex" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer" returnType="void">
    <parameter index="1" type="flash.display::DisplayObject" optional="false"/>
    <parameter index="2" type="int" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="prevScene" declaredBy="flash.display::MovieClip" returnType="void"/>
  <method name="nextScene" declaredBy="flash.display::MovieClip" returnType="void"/>
  <method name="addChild" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer" returnType="flash.display::DisplayObject">
    <parameter index="1" type="flash.display::DisplayObject" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="stop" declaredBy="flash.display::MovieClip" returnType="void"/>
  <method name="addEventListener" declaredBy="flash.events::EventDispatcher" returnType="void">
    <parameter index="1" type="String" optional="false"/>
    <parameter index="2" type="Function" optional="false"/>
    <parameter index="3" type="Boolean" optional="true"/>
    <parameter index="4" type="int" optional="true"/>
    <parameter index="5" type="Boolean" optional="true"/>
  </method>
  <method name="startDrag" declaredBy="flash.display::Sprite" returnType="void">
    <parameter index="1" type="Boolean" optional="true"/>
    <parameter index="2" type="flash.geom::Rectangle" optional="true"/>
  </method>
  <method name="stopDrag" declaredBy="flash.display::Sprite" returnType="void"/>
  <method name="startTouchDrag" declaredBy="flash.display::Sprite" returnType="void">
    <parameter index="1" type="int" optional="false"/>
    <parameter index="2" type="Boolean" optional="true"/>
    <parameter index="3" type="flash.geom::Rectangle" optional="true"/>
    <metadata name="API">
      <arg key="" value="667"/>
    </metadata>
  </method>
  <method name="removeEventListener" declaredBy="flash.events::EventDispatcher" returnType="void">
    <parameter index="1" type="String" optional="false"/>
    <parameter index="2" type="Function" optional="false"/>
    <parameter index="3" type="Boolean" optional="true"/>
  </method>
  <method name="stopTouchDrag" declaredBy="flash.display::Sprite" returnType="void">
    <parameter index="1" type="int" optional="false"/>
    <metadata name="API">
      <arg key="" value="667"/>
    </metadata>
  </method>
  <method name="willTrigger" declaredBy="flash.events::EventDispatcher" returnType="Boolean">
    <parameter index="1" type="String" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="dispatchEvent" declaredBy="flash.events::EventDispatcher" returnType="Boolean">
    <parameter index="1" type="flash.events::Event" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="hasEventListener" declaredBy="flash.events::EventDispatcher" returnType="Boolean">
    <parameter index="1" type="String" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="getChildAt" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer" returnType="flash.display::DisplayObject">
    <parameter index="1" type="int" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="getChildByName" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer" returnType="flash.display::DisplayObject">
    <parameter index="1" type="String" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="getGUILoader" declaredBy="pim::PClient" returnType="pim.loader::PGUILoader"/>
  <method name="getSessionHandler" declaredBy="pim::PClient" returnType="pim.loader::PSessionLoader"/>
  <method name="getCommandHandler" declaredBy="pim::PClient" returnType="pim.loader::PCommandLoader"/>
  <method name="onStart" declaredBy="pim::PClient" returnType="void"/>
  <method name="swapChildrenAt" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer" returnType="void">
    <parameter index="1" type="int" optional="false"/>
    <parameter index="2" type="int" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="contains" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer" returnType="Boolean">
    <parameter index="1" type="flash.display::DisplayObject" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="swapChildren" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer" returnType="void">
    <parameter index="1" type="flash.display::DisplayObject" optional="false"/>
    <parameter index="2" type="flash.display::DisplayObject" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="addChildAt" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer" returnType="flash.display::DisplayObject">
    <parameter index="1" type="flash.display::DisplayObject" optional="false"/>
    <parameter index="2" type="int" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="removeChild" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer" returnType="flash.display::DisplayObject">
    <parameter index="1" type="flash.display::DisplayObject" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="getObjectsUnderPoint" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer" returnType="Array">
    <parameter index="1" type="flash.geom::Point" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="areInaccessibleObjectsUnderPoint" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer" returnType="Boolean">
    <parameter index="1" type="flash.geom::Point" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="removeChildAt" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer" returnType="flash.display::DisplayObject">
    <parameter index="1" type="int" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="globalToLocal" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject" returnType="flash.geom::Point">
    <parameter index="1" type="flash.geom::Point" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="localToGlobal" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject" returnType="flash.geom::Point">
    <parameter index="1" type="flash.geom::Point" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="getBounds" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject" returnType="flash.geom::Rectangle">
    <parameter index="1" type="flash.display::DisplayObject" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="getRect" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject" returnType="flash.geom::Rectangle">
    <parameter index="1" type="flash.display::DisplayObject" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="nextFrame" declaredBy="flash.display::MovieClip" returnType="void"/>
  <method name="prevFrame" declaredBy="flash.display::MovieClip" returnType="void"/>
  <method name="gotoAndPlay" declaredBy="flash.display::MovieClip" returnType="void">
    <parameter index="1" type="Object" optional="false"/>
    <parameter index="2" type="String" optional="true"/>
  </method>
  <method name="hitTestPoint" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject" returnType="Boolean">
    <parameter index="1" type="Number" optional="false"/>
    <parameter index="2" type="Number" optional="false"/>
    <parameter index="3" type="Boolean" optional="true"/>
  </method>
  <method name="hitTestObject" declaredBy="flash.display::DisplayObject" returnType="Boolean">
    <parameter index="1" type="flash.display::DisplayObject" optional="false"/>
  </method>
</type>
```

Comment: Is all of this code compiled into the same swf, or are you working with multiple swf files?

Comment: Do you ever see the message `"Client(): Client initiated"` being traced out?

Comment: @frankhermes - Yes. Like I said, with strict mode off, everything works/traces how it should.

Comment: I explained a bit more the weird errors and scenarios of this particular error down under The_asMan's post. It's by far the weirdest glitch I've ever encountered in my years of programming; that includes ANY language.

Comment: Is PClient linked to a library symbol or are you creating the instance from Actionscript?

Comment: @Andrew Traviss - It is the class that the document object uses (document class).

Comment: Call describeType() on PClient.getInstance() just before the error triggers and see what comes up.

Comment: @Andrew Traviss - Added the output of that call to the post. Everything looks fine :X

Comment: @Andrew Traviss - I added "dynamic" to the class just to see what it would do. It seems to compile fine now *with* strict mode on. I know what a dynamic class is, but are there any unforeseen downsides to it?

Comment: @Andrew Traviss - Now I took out dynamic just to see if it really was the solution to the error: it STILL compiles just fine with strict mode on. This is by far the strangest glitch ever.

Comment: Adding describeType made the problem disappear? I certainly wasn't expecting that.

Comment: @Andrew Traviss - Nono, adding/removing the `dynamic` label on the PClient class magically fixed it. Weirdest thing ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the event that my comment is buried, I'll formalize it as a response:

Get rid of the static class reference and the quasi-singleton style access to your document class. Instead, use dependency injection like this:

```
public function PClient()
{
    // Trace
    trace("Client(): Client initiated");

    // Create session handler/loader
    _sessionLoader = new PSessionLoader(this);

    // Create command loader
    _cmdLoader = new PCommandLoader(this);


    ...


    addChild(_guiLoader);

    // Call on start
    onStart();
}
```

Rewrite your classes like PCommandLoader to construct with a reference to a PClient, or use an interface reference to pass in PClient's public interface. Or, do this:

```
_cmdLoader = new PCommandLoader();
_cmdLoader.init(this);
```

Again, "this" is a reference to your document class object, but it need not be a PClient type variable, it could (arguably should) be an interface type.

It sounds like you've tried this approach, but without seeing the resulting code, it's difficult to be sure you've done exactly what I expect. I would not expect the 1195 error to persist with this approach, since I do it all the time.

Comment: I had tried that. I got the same errors when I referenced the stored PClient object from passing `this`. :P But yea like I said adding/removing `dynamic` on the class magically fixed it.

Comment: That's great, but it's not a fix I'd be satisfied with. Nothing about software development is magic; when you don't understand the problem, or the nature of the fix, these sort of bugs tend to come back to haunt you, usually in the 11th hour :-/ I can tell you right now that there *should* be no problem with passing 'this', and nothing in your code needs the dynamic keyword, which means using it is only suppressing some manner of compile time type/class path checks. Very unsettling to me! I'd consider the 'dynamic' thing a clue, not a fix. Check for package hierarchy/namespace weirdness.

Comment: I know, I said setting dynamic fixed it, then to test if that was really the solution, I took it out expecting the error to return. It didn't -__- It might have been a weird project caching fluke, I'm not sure. I know nothing in programming is "magic" haha, just one of those things.

Answer (score -1):

getSessionHandler method is not defined as static

```
public static function getSessionHandler():PSessionLoader
```

This also explains why strict mode off compiles

[EDIT]
try this.

```
private static var instance:PClient;
public static function getInstance():PClient{
  if (instance == null) {
    instance = new PCLient(new PClient());
  }
  return instance;
}
```

Comment: I've tried it with static. It spits out:


C:\Pim Online\V2\lib\pim\loader\PCommandLoader.as, Line 149 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method getSessionHandler through a reference with static type pim:PClient.

Comment: When you are accessing PClient you are refering to it as a singleton. If you want to do it that way you need to set up the class with static everything. Is there a reason you are using this class as a singleton? Why not just rewrite it as a normal class?

Comment: It's not a *true* singleton. "This" references that particular instance. I'm referencing it through a static member; however, that static member stores the reference to the original object (instance). As you can see, none of these members are static other than the method that gets the instance. It's not a "singleton" class, it's just my way of getting it to reference that one instance.

Comment: The bizarre thing is that even when I take out **all** of the static stuff and literally pass `this` to each loader and the loader storing it, and then using that stored instance in the classes, I *still* get the "inaccessible members" error.

Comment: Also, the errors in PCommandLoader.as go away until I uncomment the line:

`// Get value
            var val:* = PClient.getInstance().getSessionHandler().getVal(params[0]);`

After that, that's when all three errors for that class show up. Without that line, there are no errors and it works as expected. It's the weirdest thing ever.

Comment: You weren't storing off your instance properly I added an edit in my answer please try to implement it.

Comment: Also let me ask you. Why do you want to use a singleton class?

Comment: @The_asMan - Still isn't what I was trying to accomplish with the "Singleton" instance. You just gave me a basic class that enforces singleton. This doesn't fix the issue, and isn't what I'm wanting.

Comment: Exactly in your constructor PClient._singleton = this; you are recreating the singleton so yes I am forcing the singleton with the code I supplied. With that being said back to your error getSessionHandler has to be labeled static. This is why you are able to compile with strict mode off as I explained before. With strict mode off it will not test for static. I asked you 2 times already why do you need a singleton and I got no response, so when you tell me this is not what you are "wanting" then explain what you "want". Your current implementation is not right and as you can see broken

Comment: I already addressed the singleton instance. It's just a way for me to get the latest instance of the class for ease of programming. It's in no way intended to be a forced singleton class. Secondly, I already told you, when I label the method as "static", I get yet ANOTHER compiler error. Please read my responses before replying, as I've already explained why this is not a valid answer.

Comment: The asMan is right. Weird errors aside, you need to rethink how you are providing access to your document class instance. There is no need to make it a class static variable, and your quasi-singleton thing is just bizarre. The proper way, I think most people would agree, is to use dependency injection: your PClient instance should pass a reference to itself to anything that needs to call its methods--ideally as an interface reference that exposes only as much as is needed by the recipient.

Comment: new PSessionLoader(this); is way cleaner than this static reference business.

Comment: If you want the latest instance of an object then use the new method to create the object and just pass it around. Singletons by definition are one instance. you can't design a singleton and expect it to have multiple instances. Please correct me if I am wrong.